# Do koalas sleep 22 hours a day?

Tags: sleep, zoology

I came across this image on Facebook from the website [Learn Something Every Day](http://www.learnsomethingeveryday.co.uk/2010/03/06):

[image]

When I searched for a reliable source, I came across several sites of the same kind ([OMG Facts](http://www.omg-facts.com/view/Facts/1885), [Snapple Real Facts](http://realfacts.snapple.com/comebacklater/),etc.) but never anything quite authoritative.

Is it true?

Comment: Narcopletic Koala bears, certainly do. :-)

Comment: It certainly isn't an authorative source, because *it doesn't even get the name right*. Koalas are not bears. ["Although taxonomically incorrect, the name koala bear is still in use today outside Australia – its use is discouraged because of the inaccuracy in the name."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koala)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, but they sleep a lot**

[image: Koala dozing]<sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Koala_dozing_nov08.jpg)</sup>

Koalas have an extremely slow metabolism because they are herbivores that eat eucalyptus exclusively. Eucalyptus is a poor nutrient (high fibre, low protein).

Because of this, they tend to sleep or rest a lot.

> Koalas spent about 4.7 h eating, 4 min travelling, 4.8 h resting while awake and 14.5 h sleeping in a 24-h period.

—[Source](http://www.publish.csiro.au/paper/ZO9850655)

While it's a lot, it isn't even close to the 22 hours in the question. Also, note that they spend *almost 5h eating*. This is again because of their diet and slow metabolism.

Also see:

> Nagy & Martin (1985) found that free-ranging koalas spend c. 80% of the time resting or sleeping. Such large periods of inactivity are believed to enable koalas to maintain relatively low energy requirements, and thus to use a poor quality diet (Cork & Sanson, 1990).

—[Source](http://users.monash.edu.au/~murray/includes/papers/Logan_Sanson2002a.pdf)